# Save Generated PDF on FTP Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html2pdf

I generated a PDF via Html2Pdf but i have no clue how i can save that file on my FTP Server and not localy.

I already tried it with JSPDF but the problem with that library was that i couldn't save the element css. So i am trying to make it work with html2pdf.

```js
  $("#printer").on("click", function(e) {

  var element = document.getElementById('qrcode');
  var worker = html2pdf().from(element).save();
  var saver = html2pdf().from(element).output();

    var data = new FormData();
        data.append("data" , saver);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'post', 'upload.php', true ); //Post to php Script to save to server
        xhr.send(data);

    });
```

I know that it is possible to pass this data to a "upload.php" file but i dont know how to achieve that.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: 1) are you able to run php code on the server which is currently serving this webpage (containing the above code)?

Comment: @Evil_skunk yes i am

Answer (score 0):

this is for html2pdfrocket.com

You can try following way

Assign following to $value and then use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
      <title>Title</title>
      <style type='text/css'>
        body{
            width: 96%;
            margin:1% 2%;
            line-height: 2em;
            letter-spacing: 0.26mm !important;
            padding:0;
            font-family:helvetica,sans serif;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
         SOME CSS CODE
    </style>
</head>
<body>
SOME HTML CODE
```

$postdata = http_build_query(
                    array(
                        'apikey' => $apikey,
                        'value' => $value,
                        'MarginBottom' => '30',
                        'MarginTop' => '15'
                    )
                    );

```
            $opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $postdata
                )
            );

            $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

            // Convert the HTML string to a PDF using those parameters
            $result = file_get_contents('http://api.html2pdfrocket.com/pdf', false, $context);
            file_put_contents('url_to_save/agreement.pdf', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little bit on the remote FTP server, so maybe you need a little bit Try&Error to get the connection working

#### Your JS Code:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , saver);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'post', 'upload.php', true ); //Post to php Script to save to server
    xhr.send(data);

});
```

I have not tested it with Html2Pdf, but for now I assume saver contain the full generated pdf-bibary

The JS will send the file-Content to a `upload.php` file on the server

#### Your upload.php

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){

    //$_POST['data'] will contain everything sent by ajax
    $pdfContent = $_POST['data'];

    //tmpFile to store the pdf - will be removed automatically
    $tmpFile = tmpfile();
    fwrite($tmpFile, $pdfContent);

    //connect and login to a ftp server
    $ftp_server = "ftp.xx.com";
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

    //probably login with user/pw
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);


    //upload tmp-file - choose filename on server
    if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "fileNameOnServer.pdf", $tmpFile, FTP_ASCII)){
      echo "Successfully uploaded file";
    }
    else {
      echo "Error uploading file";
    }

    //close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}
?>
```

See inline-comments, hopefully it's clear what's going on, overall you should follow these steps:

- Take the posted data from the Ajax Request
- Write Content to a temporary file (=the pdf-file)
- connect to ftp server
- upload that file

In case your ftp server requires ssl look into `ftp_ssl_connect`.
In case of errors while connecting/login php should raise warnings, so probably check your error log

Comment: I will try that tomorrow thanks for your answer though really appreciate it 